# OpenWeatherMap - Get forecast data from JSON

Tags: php, json, openweathermap

I'm trying to get the weather forecast with the Openweathermap API using a code I found looking for on the site, but I do not get any output. This is the content of the function:

```
$city="Rivanazzano";
$country="IT"; 
$url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=".$city.",".$country."&units=metric&cnt=7&lang=it&appid=MY_API_KEY";
$json=file_get_contents($url);
$data=json_decode($json,true);

$HTML ="<p>";

foreach($data['list'] as $day => $value) {
    $HTML .="Max temperature for day " . $day . " will be " . $value['temp']['max'] . "<br />" ;
}

$HTML .="</p>";

return $HTML;
```

but as I said I can not get the data, I think the problem lies in the fact that the JSON that is returned to me by the API is structured differently from that reported in the discussion. The JSON is this:

```
Array

[city] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3169258
        [name] => Rivanazzano
        [coord] => Array
            (
                [lon] => 9.0142
                [lat] => 44.9308
            )

        [country] => IT
        [population] => 4429
    )

[cod] => 200
[message] => 1.5395815
[cnt] => 7
[list] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [dt] => 1550401200
                [temp] => Array
                    (
                        [day] => 9.69
                        [min] => -1.23
                        [max] => 9.69
                        [night] => -1.23
                        [eve] => 3.5
                        [morn] => 9.69
                    )

                [pressure] => 1015.56
                [humidity] => 71
                [weather] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 800
                                [main] => Clear
                                [description] => cielo sereno
                                [icon] => 01d
                            )

                    )

                [speed] => 1.38
                [deg] => 320
                [clouds] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [dt] => 1550487600
                [temp] => Array
                    (
                        [day] => 10.84
                        [min] => -1.13
                        [max] => 12.03
                        [night] => -0.04
                        [eve] => 5.93
                        [morn] => -1.13
                    )

                [pressure] => 1014.43
                [humidity] => 89
                [weather] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 800
                                [main] => Clear
                                [description] => cielo sereno
                                [icon] => 01d
                            )

                    )

                [speed] => 1.62
                [deg] => 268
                [clouds] => 0
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [dt] => 1550574000
                [temp] => Array
                    (
                        [day] => 10.63
                        [min] => -1.57
                        [max] => 11.46
                        [night] => 2.31
                        [eve] => 6.16
                        [morn] => -1.57
                    )

                [pressure] => 1012.78
                [humidity] => 88
                [weather] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 800
                                [main] => Clear
                                [description] => cielo sereno
                                [icon] => 01d
                            )

                    )

                [speed] => 1.81
                [deg] => 279
                [clouds] => 0
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [dt] => 1550660400
                [temp] => Array
                    (
                        [day] => 9.83
                        [min] => 0.13
                        [max] => 10.78
                        [night] => 0.5
                        [eve] => 5.54
                        [morn] => 0.13
                    )

                [pressure] => 1014.53
                [humidity] => 93
                [weather] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 500
                                [main] => Rain
                                [description] => pioggia leggera
                                [icon] => 10d
                            )

                    )

                [speed] => 1.92
                [deg] => 347
                [clouds] => 8
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [dt] => 1550746800
                [temp] => Array
                    (
                        [day] => 9.9
                        [min] => 5.78
                        [max] => 9.9
                        [night] => 6.69
                        [eve] => 8.44
                        [morn] => 5.78
                    )

                [pressure] => 1014.1
                [humidity] => 0
                [weather] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 500
                                [main] => Rain
                                [description] => pioggia leggera
                                [icon] => 10d
                            )

                    )

                [speed] => 1.83
                [deg] => 349
                [clouds] => 29
                [rain] => 1.1
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [dt] => 1550833200
                [temp] => Array
                    (
                        [day] => 8.59
                        [min] => 3.21
                        [max] => 8.59
                        [night] => 3.21
                        [eve] => 6.54
                        [morn] => 5.17
                    )

                [pressure] => 1016.34
                [humidity] => 0
                [weather] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 500
                                [main] => Rain
                                [description] => pioggia leggera
                                [icon] => 10d
                            )

                    )

                [speed] => 6.51
                [deg] => 81
                [clouds] => 84
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [dt] => 1550919600
                [temp] => Array
                    (
                        [day] => 6.75
                        [min] => 1.46
                        [max] => 6.75
                        [night] => 1.46
                        [eve] => 4.99
                        [morn] => 2.09
                    )

                [pressure] => 1019.49
                [humidity] => 0
                [weather] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 500
                                [main] => Rain
                                [description] => pioggia leggera
                                [icon] => 10d
                            )

                    )

                [speed] => 3.98
                [deg] => 54
                [clouds] => 19
                [rain] => 1.14
            )

    )
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: May I ask what type of account you're signed up for? Free, startup, developer, etcetera.  I noticed that free accounts cannot use the 'Daily Forecast' API.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like a php array is returned so if you would remove the json_decode function (as its not json but already a php array) you should be able to get data like $result['cod'] and get 200 back. Hope this helps

Comment: The body of the response returned by the API is JSON unless specified to be XML.  The json_decode is needed to serialize this into a php object.

I've tested with this code on the command line substituting my API key.

`<?php
$url = "http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=MY-API-KEY";
$json=file_get_contents($url);
$data=json_decode($json,true);
echo $json;`

Comment: so the example of the data structure is before or after you use the json_decode() ?

Comment: The example of the data structure is after json_decode and I get it with echo '<pre>', print_r ($ data, 1), '</ pre>';

If I remove the json_decode function, what should I write? $ Data = $ json; ?

Answer (score 0):

Let try it .I hope it will be helpful for you.

```
$city    = 'Dhaka';
$country = 'BD';
$url     = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=' . $city . ',' . $country . '&units=metric&cnt=7&lang=en&appid=c0c4a4b4047b97ebc5948ac9c48c0559';
$json    = file_get_contents( $url );
$data    = json_decode( $json, true );
$data['city']['name'];
// var_dump($data );

foreach ( $data['list'] as $day => $value ) {
    echo 'Max temperature for day ' . $day
    . ' will be ' . $value['temp']['max'] . '<br />';
    echo '<img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' . $value['weather'][0]['icon'] . '.png" class="weather-icon" />';

}
```